# how to append additional characters into a string in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

For Example let's take `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` is the *string*.
 In this string I need to append `_` instead of `spaces` in between two `words` and append word `tag:` in front of each `word`.

i.e
`tag:The_tag:quick_tag:brown_tag:fox_tag:jumps_tag:over_tag:the_tag:lazy_tag:dog`

How to do this with `Postgresql`

---

I've tried

```
select replace('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ' ', '_')
```

Comment: Have you consulted the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT 
     string_agg (b.tag,'_') as my_string
FROM (
      select  'tag:'||c.unnest||''  as tag 
      from (select unnest(string_to_array('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', ' '))) c
) b
```